# SSIS- Split output into multiple files

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS Data Tools to create data extracts from a legacy system.
Our new system needs the files that it imports to be split into 5MB files.

Is there anyway that I can split the files into separate files?
I'm thinking that because the data is already in the database, I can do a loop, or something similar, will select a certain amount of records at a time.

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If your source is SQL, use the Row_Number function against the table key to allocate a number per row e.g.

```
Row_number() OVER (Order by Customer_Id) as RowNumber
```

and then wrap your query in a CTE or make it a sub query with a where clause to give you the number of rows that will equate to a 5MD file e.g.

```
WHERE RowNumber >= 5000 and RowNumber <10000
```

You will need to call this source target several times (with different Row Start and Row End values), so probably best to

- Find number of total records in control flow and set a TotalRows parameter
- Create a loop in your control flow
- Set 3 parameters in your control flow to iterate the through each set of records and store the data in seperate files.  e.g. first loop would set

  RowStart = 0

  RowEnd = 5000

  FileName = MyFile_[date]_0_to_4999

Comment: Thank-you. This is kind of the route I was going to take. Can I ask why you use an analytical function for the row number? Also.. this might make the solution a tiny bit more difficult. This export is a list of product codes. It will be ordered by product code (but multiple rows per code is possible). There cannot be a split of product codes between multiple files. So all rows with the same code need to be in the same export file. Any ideas how this would be achieved?

Comment: The reason I used row_number is to ensure that you do not a) lose any rows b) duplicate any rows and c) could generate a fixed quantity that should roughly equate to your required file size (by calculating row size).  To that end you would have to add any columns that would male up the primary key in your data as product code is not unique.

Comment: As you need to keep product codes together, rank might suit your need as the same product codes will be given the same rank.  If you use rank, you will not be able to accurately determine the max file size (as you may get 10000 product code x) so you will have to profile the data and make a guess at the average / max number of codes returned.  Give it a go and shout if you get stuck